# How to continue the Keyboard event in case the user press on something that is not F1?

Tags: wpf

I add the method "OnKeyDown" that check if the user pressed on F1. 
If the user pressed on F1 => i call some method that make some action.

But if the key is not F1 => i need to continue the simple key event ( like add the key value ( char ) to the editbox and so on )

How can i continue the simple flow ? 
How to send the key value to the editbox ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try setting eventargs.handled is true/false as your case may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with a Textbox:

Put the specific logic in your OnKeyDown event, you can use the `e.handled = true` to stop the processing.
You don't need special handling for all other key combinations as it will be added to the textbox automatically.

```
private void TextBox1_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F1)
        {
            // Your logic here
            ...


            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mytextbox.PreviewKeyDown+=(s,o)=>
{
    if(o.Key == Key.F1)
     {
         MyMethod();
         o.Handled = true;
     }
};
```